# @Async with JavaMelody @MonitoredWithSpring not working

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, java-melody, spring-async

I have problem with asynchronus execution of my code. 
Method **startConversion()** should be called **asynchronusly**. call goes trought AOP proxy.

**Everything separated works fine.** Problem occurs when I put together @Async and @MonitoredWithSpring annotations

javamelody is defined in webxml in first xml - OK

Spring async support is defiend in xml - OK

Code works well without @MonitoredWithSpring.  **But i need this bean to be monitored.**

Sample code:

```
@MonitoredWithSpring //L1 - if this line removed @async will work
public interface IOfficeConversionService {
    void startConversion ();
}
```

Implementing class

```
@Service
public class COfficeConversionSevice implements IOfficeConversionService {
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Async ("officeFileConversionExecutor")
    public void startConversion () {
         //ASYNC work
    }
}
```

> - With L1 present, code will call method startConversion() **synchronusly**.
> - Without L1 everything works fine, and method startConversion() is called **asynchronusly** in new thread

In stacktrace don't even create async pointcut.
@Async annotation is never processed by its postProcessor.  @Transactional works, and transaction is created.  No error in initialization

Spring configuration

```
<context:annotation-config />
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<task:executor id="mailexecutor" pool-size="25-100" queue-capacity="1000" rejection-policy="ABORT"  />
<task:executor id="pnpexecutor" pool-size="5"  />
<task:executor id="officeFileConversionExecutor" pool-size="5"  />
<task:scheduler id="systemScheduler" pool-size="5" />
<task:annotation-driven executor="mailexecutor" scheduler="systemScheduler"/>
```

Can you help me? Some suggestion ?
I am out of ideas.

Comment: Does it work with async and without transactional?

Comment: Post your configuration...